# Android studio, How to send data over http?

Tags: android, http

Developing my first basic android app, Below is how i am opening a connection and it works good.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.mocky.io/v2/568e3d730f0000da3fd1831b");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Now, how to send data or json object on this connection? This just opens a connection, where comes the authentication? does the authentication code be before opening the connection or how does it work?

Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: I suggest you to use Android Volley for HTTP/HTTPS communication and data exchange over network. See the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data in Api Get

```
String loginUrl = getString(R.string.loginapi) + "emailid=" + emailIdEditText.getText().toString().trim() + "&password=" + passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

 sendGet(loginUrl); //TODO:Use Async Task to execute these kind of operations

 // HTTP GET request
    public String sendGet(String apiUrl) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

If you are sending JSON string to URL please follow the steps
create model, assign values to object.
Convert object to string using GSON library(Recommended)

```
GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonb.create();
        String regString = gson.toJson(--Object--);
        String createTeamURL = getString(R.string.createTeamapi);
```